# dodecahedron calendar specific weeks colors

Tags: color, tikz-styles, calendar

I've seen this calendar : http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/paper-folding/
and I would like to add colors for specific lines (weeks) but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the manual of this library (pgfmanual, chapter 27). You can do something like `if (between=\year-\month-\day+8 and \year-\month-\day+10)
[red]`. That might help you to mark specific weeks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to that texample. Worth the sticky fingers any time! http://i.imgur.com/Pa3svor.jpg

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment, I used made a small example using the template you linked to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,folding}

\begin{document}
    \sffamily\scriptsize
    \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,
        every calendar/.style={
            at={(-8ex,4ex)},
            week list,
            month label above centered, 
            month text=\bfseries\textcolor{red}{\%mt} \%y0,
            if={(Sunday) [black!50]}
        }]
    \calendar [dates=\the\year-01-01 to \the\year-01-last]
    if (between=2013-01-07 and 2013-01-13)[red];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach was to use the sundays (extended and shifted) to color the rules, because even the first week has a sunday. By changing these nodes in width and coloring them (opacity such that the other days are still readable), one obtains all weeks as colored ones, despite the last ones

Then i introduced some variables to obtain different colorings, which are set each sunday (and at the beginning of each month using `etoolbox` and `style/.code`, hence my solution reads

```
\documentclass{article}
% Folding + calendar example from the PGF manual.
%
% Author: Till Tantau
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,folding}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>

\begin{comment}
:Title: Foldable dodecahedron with Calendar
:Tags: Calendars; Manual
:Author: Till Tantau

An example of the folding library and the folding library, straight from
the manual.
\end{comment}

\newbool{firstweek}
\setbool{firstweek}{true}
\newbool{evenweek}
\setbool{evenweek}{true}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{weekstyle/.style={nodes={minimum width=10em,text width=10em,minimum height=1\baselineskip, fill=blak,opacity=.2,text opacity=1,align=right}}}
    \tikzset{checkweekstyle/.code={
        \ifbool{firstweek}
        {
            \global\setbool{firstweek}{false}
            \tikzset{weekstyle/.style={nodes={minimum width=10em,text width=10em,minimum height=1\baselineskip, fill=black,opacity=.2,text opacity=1,align=right}}}
        }{
            \ifbool{evenweek}
            {
                \global\setbool{evenweek}{false}
                \tikzset{weekstyle/.style={nodes={minimum width=10em,text width=10em,minimum height=1\baselineskip, fill=black,opacity=.1,text opacity=1,align=right}}}
            }{
                \global\setbool{evenweek}{true}
                \tikzset{weekstyle/.style={nodes={minimum width=10em,text width=10em,minimum height=0.9\baselineskip, fill=white,opacity=.2,text opacity=1,align=right}}}
            }
        }
        }}
   \sffamily\scriptsize
    \begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,
        every calendar/.style={
            at={(-8ex,4ex)},
            week list,
            month label above centered, 
            month text=\bfseries\textcolor{blue}{\%mt} \%y0,
            if={(Sunday) [black!50,checkweekstyle,weekstyle]}
        }]
    \tikzset{init/.code={\global\setbool{firstweek}{true}\global\setbool{evenweek}{true}}}
    \tikzfoldingdodecahedron[
        folding line length=2.5cm,
        face 1={ \calendar [init, dates=\the\year-01-01 to \the\year-01-last];},
        face 2={ \calendar [init, dates=\the\year-02-01 to \the\year-02-last];},
        face 3={ \calendar [init, dates=\the\year-03-01 to \the\year-03-last];},
        face 4={ \calendar [init, dates=\the\year-04-01 to \the\year-04-last];},
        face 5={ \calendar [init, dates=\the\year-05-01 to \the\year-05-last];},
        face 6={ \calendar [init, dates=\the\year-06-01 to \the\year-06-last];},
        face 7={ \calendar [init, dates=\the\year-07-01 to \the\year-07-last];},
        face 8={ \calendar [init, dates=\the\year-08-01 to \the\year-08-last];},
        face 9={ \calendar [init, dates=\the\year-09-01 to \the\year-09-last];},
        face 10={\calendar [init, dates=\the\year-10-01 to \the\year-10-last];},
        face 11={\calendar [init, dates=\the\year-11-01 to \the\year-11-last];},
        face 12={\calendar [init, dates=\the\year-12-01 to \the\year-12-last];}
    ];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Drawbacks**

the last line is not colored some times, because it has not a sunday in a month (most of the times).

So a change would be to introduce a background color for the month (and hence also the first week) and use the monday nodes to color the rows starting from the second.

Finally the second (odd) weeks should be white, because the 5th week is not colored, hence in alternating, the 3rd should not be, too.

Here's an image of the result

[image]

Comment: if you change your scheme to "mark the even weeks (by Sunday)" it should work perfectly fine. The only possible month with 4 weeks is an April and that one has to end with a Sunday. For every other week you have an alternating colour scheme that is white on the first and last week (so no problem with missing Sundays)